# ionic facebook and barcodescanner issue

Tags: android, facebook, ionic-framework, barcode-scanner

I have a problem with facebook plugin and barcode scanner, first i created a projects separate to check how facebook plugin work and was working perfect, but when I added the facebook plugin to my project where im using barcodescanner plugin i cant run the project in android, I got the following exception:

```
 BUILD FAILED

Total time: 10.111 secs
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/zxing/BarcodeFormat.class

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/zxing/BarcodeFormat.class

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova run android (exit code 1).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1 : Install Barcode Scanner Plugin:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/barcode-scanner
```

Step 2: Install Facebook plugin: (Use the below facebook plugin version)

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4@1.7.4 --variable APP_ID="****" --variable APP_NAME="****"
npm install --save @ionic-native/facebook
```

Step 3: Open the file `facebookconnect.xml` from this path :  `yourapp\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\values` and add two lines inside `<resources></resources>`

```
<resources>
  <string name="fb_app_id">***your_app_id***</string>
  <string name="fb_app_name">***your_app_name***</string>
</resources>
```

Step 4: Command :  `cordova clean` - allow cordova clean your app

Step 5: Command :  `cordova build` - check cordova build your app

Step 6: Command :  `ionic cordova build android` - Build your app

Answer (score 1):

Changing the required version of the Facebook plugin resolved the issue for me.

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4@1.7.4 --variable APP_ID="" --variable APP_NAME=""
```